# MySQL query a resultset

Tags: mysql

In my database table I want to retrieve the last 10 records, and then perform further queries on this same set of results. The current query I have is this:

```
SELECT * FROM `listing`
WHERE status = 200
ORDER by created_at DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Once I have these results I want to be able to perform further queries on them, for example:

`WHERE type_id = 10`

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use a subquery:

```
select . . .
from (SELECT *
      FROM `listing`
      WHERE status = 200
      ORDER by created_at DESC
      LIMIT 10
     ) t
where . . .
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested queries in mysql or any structured/standard query language.

Just providing you a naive idea.

```
select * from (select * from 'listing' where status=200 order by created_at desc limit 10)
```

Refer to this documentation of mysql for further help

[mysql Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/subqueries_part_1.html)

Comment: This syntax is incorrect. Also, a good answer has allready been provided.

Comment: This is a correct syntax `select * from (select * from 'listing' where status=200 order by created_at desc limit 10) SubTable WHERE SubTable.type_id=10;`